# How to add SSL to RabbitMQ UI management on GKE?

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, cloud, containers, kubernetes

I am trying to set up a RabbitMQ cluster on Google Container Engine and so far it is working correctly.
To make it more secure I tried to to enabling SSL for the UI management.

Unfortunately can't make it works, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

I followed the informations shared here : https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/pull/49 (for SSL support)

I generated a self-signed certificate for testing purpose :

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /tmp/rq.key -out /tmp/rq.crt
```

Created secret for all of those variables :

```
kubectl create secret generic rabbitmq-key --from-file=/tmp/rq.key
kubectl create secret generic rabbitmq-cert --from-file=/tmp/rq.crt
```

This is what I added to my rabbitmq.yaml file for those changes :

```
    - name: RABBITMQ_SSL_CERT_FILE
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: rabbitmq-crt
          key: rq.crt
    - name: RABBITMQ_SSL_KEY_FILE
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: rabbitmq-key
          key: rq.key
```

EDIT : 
I solve the part for the credentials, apparently the secret for username and the associated password wasn't consider properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully made it https by using an ingress ressource which redirect traffic to my UI management port.

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-secret
  backend:
    serviceName: rabbitmq-management
    servicePort: 15672
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: rabbitmq-management
          servicePort: 15672
```